# Trigger angular from outside of angular-app

Tags: angularjs

Ho to trigger an event inside ngApp from the outside world?

This is my current code:

```
    // Inside old code
    console.log("Start Triggering angular");
    $('#issueSelectedPid').val(pid);
    $('#issueSelectedPid').trigger('input');
    console.log("Triggering angular");


    // inside ngApp
    <input id="issueSelectedPid" ng-model="vm.selectedPid" ng-change="vm.doMyStuffTriggerdFromTheOutsideWorld()" />
```

Are there better ways of doing this?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the scope using the below code :

```
var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=appName]');
var appScope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
var controllerScope = appScope.$$childHead;
```

controllerScope.functionName(controllerScope.vm.doMyStuffTriggerdFromTheOutsideWorld() in your case)

Comment: Good idea! I'm using the controller as syntax, and I found I could even skip the scary $$childHead and instead write: appScope.vm.doMyStuf...

Comment: :) Thanks. Included $$childHead; to cover all child scopes as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get your html element by *yourDivId* which is defining your input scope, then call $apply with something or without

```
var scope = angular.element($("#yourDivId")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.something= 'something';
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In this case my ngApp need to know about the outside world, I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: then you can get your root element in which you applied ng-app and run scope.$apply();